# How to repair this JavaScript slider code?

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm new to JS and I can't make this script work. I think I know what the problem is but I don't know how to fix it.

```js
//images
const image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
const image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
const images = [image1, image2];

//buttons
const suivant = document.getElementById('button1');
const precedent = document.getElementById('button2');

//change images

suivant.onclick = function() {
  i = 0;
  if (i = 0, true) {
    i++
    images[i];
  } else if (images[1]) {
    i--
    images[i];
  }

};
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Sonsie+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div style="width: 60%; margin: auto;">
  <div id="exemple1" name="slide" style="display: flex;">
    <img id="image1" class="présente" name="slide" src="https://lemag.nikonclub.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/08.jpg" height="500" alt="" />
    <img id="image2" class="présente" name="slide" src="https://www.travelercar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/4a36e314016aa914f203ea6b7d579dc6_large.jpeg" height="500" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>


<div id="bouton" style='display: flex'>
  <button id="button1" style="margin-right: 15px;">suivant</button>
  <button id="button2">précédent</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post also the html content pls?

Comment: The code is edited !

Comment: What do you think `if (i=0, true)` does? When will it ever be false?

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to remove that from the code. And i just dont want any condition for the if to work so i just thought that true would use it without any conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The onClick event handler doesn't seem to make too much sense.
I'd expect that what you want is something like this:

```
//images
const image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
const image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
const images = [image1,image2];

//buttons
const suivant = document.getElementById('button1');
const precedent = document.getElementById('button2');

//change images

images[0].style.display ="block";
images[1].style.display ="none";

suivant.onclick = function(){
    // Loop through each image and check if it's hidden or shown
    images.forEach((image) => {
        // If hidden -> make it display block
        if (image.style.display === "none") image.style.display = "block";
        // Else if shown -> make it display none
        else image.style.display = "none";
    });
};
```

If you'd want to make this work for more than two images:

```
//images
const image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
const image2 = document.getElementById('image2');
const image3 = document.getElementById('image3');
const images = [image1,image2, image3];
// Store the index of the currently active image.
let activeImage = 0;

//buttons
const next = document.getElementById('button1');
const prev = document.getElementById('button2');

//change images

images[0].style.display ="block";
images[1].style.display ="none";

next.onclick = function(){
    // Hide currently active index
    images[activeImage].style.display = "none";
    // Show the index that's next up
    images[++activeImage + 1].style.display = "block";
};

prev.onclick = function(){
    // Hide currently active index
    images[activeImage].style.display = "none";
    // Show the index that's next up
    images[activeImage - 1].style.display = "block";
};
```

Comment: That code worked but i dont really understand why it worked. Im going to look a bit more into it. Thanks for you time !

Comment: This only works for 2 images, if you want to make it work for multiple images it gets a bit more complicated. I'd suggest you try and figure this out first :)

Answer (score 1):

I think is cleaner to use an array of images without putting all the images in html and keeping track who is visible and hide others. Create a image element who will serve as container and only change the src of it.

Imagine that you will have 20+ images, instead of putting them as `html` elements in page give the `source` to it and change the container `src` with elements from array. (the below code does not treat the case if the counter reaches the max number of elements from array)

```js
const images = [
  "https://www.travelercar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/4a36e314016aa914f203ea6b7d579dc6_large.jpeg",

  "https://lemag.nikonclub.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/08.jpg",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/000000"

];

//buttons
const suivant = document.getElementById('button1');
const precedent = document.getElementById('button2');


var counter = 0;

precedent.onclick = function() {
  animateWithFadeImg("currentImage", function() {
    document.getElementById("currentImage").src = images[--counter];
  })
}

suivant.onclick = function() {
  animateWithFadeImg("currentImage", function() {
    document.getElementById("currentImage").src = images[++counter];
  })
}

function animateWithFadeImg(elementId, callback) {
  $("#" + elementId).fadeOut("slow", callback)
  $("#" + elementId).fadeIn("slow")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Intitulé de ma page</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Sonsie+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 60%; margin: auto;">
    <div id="exemple1" name="slide" style="display: flex;">
      <!-- image container -->
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF" id="currentImage" height="300" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="bouton" style='display: flex'>
    <button id="button1" style="margin-right: 15px;">suivant</button>
    <button id="button2">précédent</button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

EDIT -- After the comment with animation:

Builtin jQuery has a series of animation, for your demo I used [fadeIn and fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/).

The principle is easy:

```
$("#elementId").fadeIn( "slow", function() {
   // Animation complete, add logic as you please
});
```

Based on this, I passed the function as param, because we need to change the `src` with `images[--counter]` or `images[--counter]`. The order of calls are : `fadeOut` the current image, change the `src`, `fadeIn` to the initial opacity. Through this you will obtain a nice continuous animation. :)

Comment: This code is so simple ! Thanks ! Can i add animations to this code ?

Comment: You mean transition between images?

Comment: Yes, im mean that

Comment: @Gobi I changed the answer a bit, if you have questions, feel free to ask!